# Color theory: "substracting two grays"

Tags: math, colors

I don't know if this community is the right place for this kind of questions but probably is...

This is the first time I have to "work" with color theory so I don't know much about it...
This time I'll only have grayscale pictures so it will be easyer i hope.

I need to get a gradient out of an image for a java project.
What I have is a flat gray background image with a simple dark gradient on it. [Example](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2w6gxnr.jpg)

And i want to get a transparent gradient like [this](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2vwh9q8.jpg).

With some tricks on photoshop I found out that if my background color is `RGB(83,83,83)` a pixel in the starting image that is `RGB(57,57,57)` in my result image will be a **31%**(transparence) black.

I could build a java app with some bufferedimages but I don't know the maths behind this **31%**...

So i need a math rule to substract two grays and get a transparent black :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1 - 57/83) * 100%  = 31.3%
```

This resembles some alpha blending formula.